# OAuth and Cookies

Tags: php, session, authentication, cookies, oauth

I am currently implementing an OAuth authentication 3 legged strategy using 2.0. I have come across a problem:

What's the best way to remember the client's session when logging in using Oauth.

Currently what I'm doing is setting a cookie on the client that matches my session ID on the server. This is of course equivalent to a normal cookie session based login. Then in the session, I keep track of the access token that I got when I used the Auth Code and exchanged it for the access token.

As you can see, state is kept in sync between the client and the server via the cookie/session id, and the access token is kept only in the server and in relationship to the session id.

However I've read that this is insecure, and that OAuth should be stateless (restful) style, so cookies should not be required, especially if the client is a machine client and not a browser client. Some resources have mentioned that the client should store all the necessary credentials in order to authenticate any request to the app. Does this mean I should store the access token in the browser's header? What about the auth code from the redirect, should this be stored on the browser's header as well? (And should these codes/tokens be encrypted/signed on the browser's headers) (and how would you do this using PHP?)

Resources like this: http://sitr.us/2011/08/26/cookies-are-bad-for-you.html says a client side rich javascript app could keep track of the access token and pass it in on every XHR request? But of course not every client is a javascript app such as machine clients.

Comment: tbh, i never understood this crap about needing to be stateless when the service in question forces you to use a temporary token. This token forces you to have a state and thus makes this requirement obsolete anyways, am i wrong?

Comment: Well stateless means that the server doesn't keep tracking the state of the client. So the client token simply authenticates the request, but the server isn't tracking it in the DB. Basically there's no temporary tokens in the DB. The client should be tracking all state, such as shopping carts would be done on the client side... etc.

Comment: ok, tnx. that also means that we dont get temporary tokens/passwords for subsequent requests to a authenticated service, right? But I think we are derailing this question. ;)

Comment: Yes I was thinking about that. It may be that the client is the one that gets the token from an authenticated service, and it is the client who stores the token as well. If the server needs the token, the client passes the token to the server via the headers, but the server never stores the token, it just keeps asking for the token on every request. And that is the crux of this question, how to do this for auth codes as well and whether doing so is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store the token in a regular session.
The idea of it being stateless is that each request carries all the required validation information.

Of course this may require more work on the client side in order to ensure all requests carry all the required data.

One of the benefits of REST's statelessness is that it is simpler to have a distributed implementation. Every request has all the necessary data so you don't even need to hit the same server twice, each server can validate on its own.